# Conectar em um host via SSH e ir para outro com o túnel ssh - Python

Tags: python, shell, ssh

O código abaixo (main.py) realiza o acesso a um host através do SSH e cria um tunel para o IP ser acessado por 127.0.0.1:

```
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from paramiko import SSHClient

class SSH:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ssh = SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1',port='22',username='teste',password='teste')

        def exec_cmd(self,cmd):
            stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
                print (stderr.read())
            else:
                print (stdout.read())


server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    '192.168.1.1',
    ssh_username="teste2",
    ssh_password="teste2",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
)

server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh = SSH()
    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.ssh.exec_command("hostname")
    retorno = stdout.read()
    print (retorno)

server.stop()
```

Estou tentando acessar uma máquina específica mas para isso, tenho que acessar uma máquina inicialmente por razões de rede.

A topologia acessada pelo Putty é: acessar a conexão inicial (aquela para a qual você criou as regras de rede) e criar um tunel SSH para o IP que deseja. Com isso acessando novamente o putty informando o IP 127.0.0.1 mais a porta do seu tunel chegará a máquina desejada.

Basicamente acesso inicial e vou para outra maquina dentro da rede

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                            |
-------------+              |    +----------+               +---------+
      HOST   |              |    |   HOST   |               |   HOST  |
    MAIN.PY  | -- SSH ----> |    |  INITIAL | -- TUNNEL --> |  WANTED |
-------------+              |    +----------+               +---------+
                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Conforme declarado no código acima, só consigo acessar o primeiro host. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: o conceito de túnel do SSH acho que não funciona como está imaginando, quando vc cria um túnel via SSH quando você loga via ssh no servidor, se tiver um túnel configurado por exemplo no client Puty, você poderia acessar a porta configurada no túnel como se fosse uma porta local, o que vc tá querendo é acessar um SO para ganhar acesso a outro SO

Comment: Perfeito Ederwander, isso mesmo que desejo. Acessar um SO para obter acesso a outro SO por questões de rede. Porem queria fazer isso em python

Comment: então né o `SSHTunnelForwarder` não faz isso que vc quer ... rapaz, até imaginei uma maneira aqui de fazer o que vc precisa, mas é muita gambiarra huahuahuahua

Comment: Poxa, achei que daria pra fazer. Então kk, eu pensei em conectar no primeiro SO e mandar comandos de SSH pra ele.. mais é gambiarra..

Comment: é bem por ai que vai ser o seu caminho, só que não tem como vc em teoria digitar a senha via python para ser enviado para o segundo SO, vc deverá fazer um trust host ssh entre os dois SO's, assim vc consegue logar do primeiro SO usando SSH para o segundo sem digitar a senha SSH do segundo, ai seria só enviar os comandos ssh do primeiro SO pro Segundo `ssh usuariotrust@servidor 'ls -l'`

Comment: Eu meio que tenho em mente essa gambiarra kk. Mas tenho uma duvida, caso eu conecte no primeiro SO, tem como eu abrir um tunel para o outro SO certo?. Eu utilizo uma plataforma de automação pronta e ela faz essa mesma ideia, incia a conexão e utiliza a conexão pra abrir um tunel para o SO que desejo. Só que agora quero fazer em python..

Comment: túnel em SSH não é isso ai o que vc imagina que seja, na verdade a única maneira é que vc se logue no primeiro SO e faça com que o primeiro SO envie comandos SSH para o segundo SO, para cada comando ele abre um SSH e fecha (só abre e fecha a cada comando no segundo SO, no primeiro vc fica com a conexão ativa sempre via pytho) ... essa plataforma deve ter um usuário com chave trust permitindo que algum usuário envie comandos para o segundo SO sem precisar digitar senha ...

Comment: Entendi, então no caso eu abriria uma conexão SSH normal, e enviaria comandos remotos de SSH para o outro SO para obter acesso certo? Conseguiria me dar uma luz de como faço isso em python? kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    '192.168.1.1',
    ssh_username="teste2",
    ssh_password="teste2",
    remote_bind_address=('<IP do HOST Destino>', 22),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 10022) # Aqui você deixa o ip de loopback
)
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Perfeito Leandro, deu certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você especifica a senha do host que criou o tunel aqui: 
self.ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1',port='10022',username='root',password='root')